# Why are star domains useful compared to convex domains?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that convex domains are widely used in e.g. ODEs as they guarantee that functions will satisfy a Lipschitz condition in the domain. But why are star domains of interest? I have heard that they are useful in geometric function theory when studying Riemann surfaces or such?

Comment: Convexity is often a bit too much to ask for. Star-convex domains are not as restrictive, but nice enough that you can still guarantee many of the same properties - for example, a star-convex domain is simply connected.

Comment: They are more general.   Mathematicians love to generalize.